# Any method to check whether file is still in use on FTP location before downloading it locally

Tags: ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am downloading files from FTP using WinSCP .NET library.

My code is

```csharp
session.ExecutablePath = _appSettings["ApplicationFolderPath"] + "WinSCP.exe";
session.Open(sessionOptions);
var obj = session.ListDirectory(_appSettings["SFTP_IncomingFileFolder"]);

if (obj != null && obj.Files != null)
{
    foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileOrDo in obj.Files)
    {
        if (fileOrDo.Name == "." || fileOrDo.Name == ".." || fileOrDo.FileType == 'd' || fileOrDo.FileType == 'D')
        {
            continue;
        }

        // here I want's to check whether file is not in use  before calling  session.GetFiles(...,...).Check();
    }                    
 }
```

What I want's is to check file is not in use on FTP location before downloading it. Any idea what interface I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to test, if file is in use over FTP protocol.

Not only with WinSCP .NET assembly, but in general.

---

So all you can do is to try do download the file and gracefully handle any failure.

Comment: Wow. Answer from the author himself. Thanks Martin

Comment: Martin Any idea what particular type of exception i should catch to avoid error. I am downloading multiple files in a foreach loop. I have a single catch which will break the other downloading.

Comment: Just do not call the `.Check` method and your do not get any exception. If you want to test, use `.IsSuccess` property. See [`TransferOperationResult` Class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoperationresult).